# How to get data from API fetch using playwirght .NET

Tags: c#, .net, playwright

I'm trying to get an answer the response from an api using the fetch command that i get from chrome developer tools but i get an error when i feed it to playwright :

```
link = fetch("https://api.xx.com/graphql/public?", {
  "headers": {
  "accept": "*/*",
  "accept-language": "fr-FR",
  "authorization": "Bearer 
  YzA1ZTBiYjkyNmJkNTNjMGQ2N2YyMWU5NzJjMjkwZTdiYTRkNWFlYTI5NTAyMGZlNGEwMzFhMDM0NWUyODU5Ng",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"100\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"100\"",
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?1",
  "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Android\"",
  "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
  "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
  "Referer": "https://www.xx.fr/",
  "Referrer-Policy": "origin-when-cross-origin"
},
"method": "POST",
"mode": "cors",
"credentials": "include"
});
```

And then i use the EvaluateAsync method :

```
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
        await using var browser = await playwright.Webkit.LaunchAsync();
        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        var response = await page.EvaluateAsync<string>(link);
```

Error :

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException: SyntaxError: 
Unexpected identifier 'Not'. Expected '}' to end an object literal.
at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Connection.InnerSendMessageToServerAsync[T](String 
guid, String method, Object args) in /_/src/Playwright/Transport/Connection.cs:line 
161
at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Connection.WrapApiCallAsync[T](Func`1 action, 
Boolean isInternal) in /_/src/Playwright/Transport/Connection.cs:line 487
at Microsoft.Playwright.Core.Frame.EvaluateAsync[T](String script, Object arg) in 
/_/src/Playwright/Core/Frame.cs:line 483
```

But this doesn't work, is it an error with the string formatting ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like an issue with the JavaScript code. In C# land you are expecting to return a string from the EvaluateAsync function:

```
var response = await page.EvaluateAsync<string>(link);
```

...but the JavaScript you pass to it doesn't return anything back! If you tweaked your JS code like this I cant see any reason why it shouldn't work:

```
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

string fetchJS = @"
  fetch('https://api.xx.com/graphql/public?', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      accept: '*/*',
      accept-language: 'fr-FR',
      authorization: 'Bearer YzA1ZTBiYjkyNmJkNTNjMGQ2N2YyMWU5NzJjMjkwZTdiYTRkNWFlYTI5NTAyMGZlNGEwMzFhMDM0NWUyODU5Ng',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'sec-ch-ua': '\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"100\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"100\"',
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
      'sec-ch-ua-platform': '\"Android\"',
      'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
      'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
      'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
      Referer: 'https://www.xx.fr/',
      'Referrer-Policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin'
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include'
  }).then(response => response.text());
";

string responseText = await page.EvaluateAsync<string>(fetchJS);
```

I tweaked the JavaScript code and appended a .then method to return the response body as a text string.  The code has not been tested!